# Se puede align una div id="ajax"

Tags: html, ajax

Pregunto tengo esto:

```
<table border="0">
    <tr><td><input type="number" name="Money" id="Money" onkeyup="busqueda();"/></td>  </tr>
    <tr><td>
    <select name="valor_Crypto" id="valor"  required/>
                <option value="">SELECT CONVERT</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td><div id="texto"></div></td></tr>

</table>
```

mi problema es que quiero que (`<div id="texto">`) su resultado obtenido de ajax me salga centrico. su variable es solo text

Comment: Si el texto es lo que buscas salga al centro de su espacio, con un `text-align: center;` no alcanza?

Answer (score 0):

Usa el estilo `text-align:center` en la etiqueta `td`

```html
<table border="0">
    <tr><td><input type="number" name="Money" id="Money" onkeyup="busqueda();"/></td>  </tr>
    <tr><td>
    <select name="valor_Crypto" id="valor"  required/>
                <option value="">SELECT CONVERT</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align: center"><div id="texto"></div></td></tr>

</table>
```